# how to disable the color change on mousehover in sankeycharts Highchart . { hover: {color: '#a4edba',opacity: 1,filter: {type: 'none',}}} didnt work

Tags: highcharts

how to disable the color change on mousehover in sankeycharts Highchart .
I used { hover: {color: '#a4edba',opacity: 1,filter: {type: 'none',}}} and enableMouseTracking: false but it didn't work. Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the color at all just disable hover state.

```
series: {
  states: {
    hover: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m23qeojf/

Comment: Hi,  I had tried this and the tool tip doesn't appear if I do this and moreover all series become kind of light / opaque which I don't want . On mouse over I don't want it to become light.

Comment: In my demo tooltip appear correctly. Unfortunately, it's a Sankey feature to change the opacity of all points on hover.